# infinite copy list loop with copy constructor and pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, infinite-loop

i am having an infinite loop after it tries to insert "b" into the list.

based on my output when i run "make test | more", it inserts "a" just fine, but when it reaches "b" and tries to call the copy constructor again, thats when it gets into an infinite loop

here is my header file

```
#define DLIST_HEADER

#include <string>

struct DListNodeT;

class DListT{
    public:
        DListT();
        DListT(const DListT & src);
        ~DListT();

        DListT & operator = (const DListT & rhs);

        void Home();
        void Left();
        void Right();

        std::string Data() const;
        size_t Size() const;

        void Insert(std::string newData);
        void InsertAfter(std::string newData);
        void Delete();

    private:
        DListNodeT* head;
        DListNodeT* current;
        size_t nodeCount;
};
#endif
```

here is my cpp file

```
#include "DListT.h"

using namespace std;

void DeleteList(DListNodeT * list);
DListNodeT * CopyList(DListNodeT * src);
void AdjustCurrent(DListNodeT * srcList, DListNodeT * destList, DListNodeT * srcCurrent, DListNodeT * & destCurrent);

struct DListNodeT
{
    string data;
    DListNodeT * next{nullptr};
    DListNodeT * prev{nullptr};
};

DListT::DListT()
{
    //DListNodeT * tmp{nullptr};
    //tmp.data = "hi"; 
    
    //tmp = new DListNodeT;
    head = nullptr;
    current = nullptr;
    nodeCount = 0;
}

DListT::DListT(const DListT & src)
{
    cout << "calling copy constructor" << endl;
    
    //this was added after this was graded
    nodeCount = src.nodeCount;
    
    head = CopyList(src.head);
    
    AdjustCurrent(src.head, head, src.current, current);
    
    cout << "exiting copy constructor" << endl;
        
    /*DListNodeT * travel{nullptr};
    DListNodeT * tmp{nullptr};
    DListNodeT * tail{nullptr};
    
    head = nullptr;
    travel = src.head;
    
    while (travel != nullptr)
    {
        tmp = new DListNodeT;
        tmp->data = travel->data;
        tmp->next = nullptr;
        //tmp->prev = nullptr;
        
        if (head == nullptr)
        {
            head = tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = tmp;
            //tail->prev = tmp;
        }
        
        tail = tmp;
        travel = travel->next;
        //travel = travel->prev;
    }    
    
    nodeCount = src.nodeCount;*/
}

DListT::~DListT()
{
    DeleteList(head);
}

DListT & DListT::operator = (const DListT & rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        DeleteList(head);
        head = CopyList(rhs.head);
        nodeCount = rhs.nodeCount;
        AdjustCurrent(rhs.head, head, rhs.current, current);
    }
    
    return *this;    
}

void DeleteList(DListNodeT * list)
{
    DListNodeT * tmp{nullptr};
    DListNodeT * garbage{nullptr};
    
    if (list != nullptr) 
    {
        tmp = list;

        do 
        {
            garbage = tmp;
            tmp = garbage->next;
            delete garbage;
        } while (tmp != list);
    }
}

DListNodeT * CopyList(DListNodeT * src)
{
    DListNodeT * head{nullptr};
    DListNodeT * trace1{nullptr}; 
    DListNodeT * trace2{nullptr};
    DListNodeT * tmp{nullptr};
    
    if (src == nullptr)
    {
        head = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        //set up head pointer
        cout << "setting up new head" << endl;
        head = new DListNodeT;
        cout << "set new head" << endl;
        cout << "setting head's data to src's data" << endl;
        head->data = src->data;
        cout << "set head's data to src's data" << endl;
        cout << "setting head's next to head" << endl;
        head->next = head;
        cout << "set head's next to head" << endl;
        cout << "setting head's prev to head" << endl;
        head->prev = head;
        cout << "set head's prev to head" << endl;
                            
        //copy rest of list
        cout << "setting trace1 to src's next" << endl;   
        trace1 = src->next;
        cout << "set trace1 to src's next" << endl;
        cout << "setting trace2 to head" << endl;
        trace2 = head;
        cout << "set trace2 to head" << endl;
        
        while (/*trace1 != head*/ trace1 != src)
        {
            cout << "in copylist while loop" << endl;
            //build new nodes
            cout << "creating a new tmp node" << endl;
            
            tmp = new DListNodeT;
            
            cout << "created the tmp node" << endl;
            cout << "setting tmp's data to trace1's data" << endl;
            
            tmp->data = trace1->data;
            
            cout << "set tmp's data to trace1's data" << endl;
            cout << "setting tmp's next to null" << endl;
            
            tmp->next = nullptr;
            
            cout << "set tmp's next to null" << endl;
            cout << "data is: " << tmp->data << endl;
            
            //link into list
            cout << "setting trace2's next to tmp" << endl;
            
            trace2->next = tmp;
            
            cout << "set trace2's next to tmp" << endl;
            cout << "settings tmp's prev to trace2" << endl;
            
            tmp->prev = trace2;
            
            cout << "set tmp's prev to trace2" << endl;
            cout << "data is: " << tmp->data << endl;
            
            //make it circular
            cout << "setting tmp's next to head" << endl;
            
            tmp->next = head;
            
            cout << "set tmp's next to head" << endl;
            cout << "setting head's prev to tmp" << endl;
            
            head->prev = tmp;
            
            cout << "set head's prev to tmp" << endl;
            cout << "data is: " << tmp->data << endl;
            
            //advance next two pointers
            cout << "setting trace2 to tmp" << endl;
            
            trace2 = tmp;
            
            cout << "set trace2 to tmp" << endl;
            cout << "setting trace1 to trace1's next" << endl;
            
            trace1 = trace1->next;
            
            cout << "set trace1 to trace1's next" << endl;
            cout << "data is: " << tmp->data << endl;
            
            //cout << "nodecount is: " << nodeCount << endl;
        }
    }
    
    return head;
}

void AdjustCurrent(DListNodeT * srcList, DListNodeT * destList, DListNodeT * srcCurrent, DListNodeT * & destCurrent)
{
    DListNodeT * tmp{nullptr};
    
    if (srcCurrent == nullptr)
    {
        destCurrent = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        tmp = srcList;
        destCurrent = destList;
        
        while (tmp != nullptr and tmp != srcCurrent)
        {
            tmp = tmp->next;
            destCurrent = destCurrent->next;
        }
    }
}

void DListT::Insert(string newData)
{
    cout << "entering insert function" << endl;
    DListNodeT * tmp{nullptr};
    DListNodeT * tail{nullptr};
    
    tmp = new(DListNodeT);
    tmp->data = newData;
    tmp->next = nullptr;
    tmp->prev = nullptr;
    cout << "inserting an element into list" << endl;
    nodeCount++;
    
    // ASSUME
    // INVARIANT: (head == nullptr) == (current == nullptr)
    //         if head is null, current is null.
    //         if head is NOT null, current is NOT null

    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "entering if statement for empty list" << endl;
        // we have an empty list, there are no nodes.
        // the node we just created becomes the head/tail/current
        tmp->next = tmp;
        tmp->prev = tmp;
        current = tmp;
        head = tmp;
        cout << "exiting if statment for empty list" << endl;
    }
    else if (current == head)
    {
        cout << "enterting if state where current is equal to the head of the list" << endl;
        // this is a special case: when current points to the head, 
        // we will insert the new node _before_ the current one (head of the list)
        tmp->next = head;
        tmp->prev = head->prev;
        head->prev = tmp;
        current = tmp;
        head = tmp;
        cout << "exiting if statement where current is equal to the head of the list" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "entering else statment from insert function" << endl;
        // we have a non-empty list and we want to append to the end
        // so we insert the new node at the current node
        tail = current->prev;
        tmp->prev = tail;
        tmp->next = current;
        tail->next = tmp;
        current->prev = tmp;
        current = tmp;
        cout << "exiting else statement from insert function" << endl;
    }
    
    cout << "exiting insert function" << endl;
}

void DListT::Delete()
{
    DListNodeT * tmp{nullptr};
    DListNodeT * next{nullptr};
    DListNodeT * prior{nullptr};
    
    if (current == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "Error: Attempt to delete in an Empty List.";
    }
    else if (nodeCount == 1)
    {
//USELESS        current = tmp;
        current = nullptr;
        head = nullptr;
        delete tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        // the node we're about to delete is also the head...
        // reposition the head to the node after; otherwise it would
        // point to the node we just deleted.
        if (current == head) {
            head = current->next;
        }
        // unlink the current node
        prior = current->prev;
        next = current->next;
        prior->next = next;
        next->prev = prior;
        tmp = current;
        current = prior;
        delete tmp;    
    } 
}

size_t DListT::Size() const
{
    return nodeCount;
}

void DListT::Home()
{
    if (head != nullptr)
    {
        current = head;
    }
}

void DListT::Right()
{
    if (current != nullptr)
    {
        current = current->next; 
    }
}

void DListT::Left()
{
    if (current != nullptr)
    {
        current = current->prev; 
    }
}

void DListT::InsertAfter(string newData)
{
    DListNodeT * tmp{nullptr};
    DListNodeT * seek{nullptr};
    
    tmp = new(DListNodeT);
    tmp->data = newData;
    tmp->next = nullptr;
    tmp->prev = nullptr;
    nodeCount++;
    
    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        tmp->next = tmp;
        tmp->prev = tmp;
        current = tmp;
        head = tmp; 
    }
    else
    {

        // node after current; will now be after tmp
        seek = current->next;
        tmp->next = seek;
        tmp->prev = current;
        current->next = tmp;
        seek->prev = tmp;

        current = tmp;    
    } 
}

string DListT::Data() const
{
    string data;
    
    if (current != nullptr)
    {
        data = current->data;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error: Attempt to access Empty List.";
        data = "NO DATA";
    }
    
    return data;
}
```

here is my professor's test code

```
#include<boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include<boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/test/output_test_stream.hpp>
#include <vector>

#include "DListT.h"

using namespace std;
using boost::test_tools::output_test_stream;


void Header(string s) {
   cout << endl;
   cout << "******* Running " << s << " *******" << endl;
}

void Footer(string s) {
   cout << "******* Finished with " << s << " *******" << endl;
   cout << endl;
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE( DListTTest )

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(constructor_test) {
    DListT list;

    Header("Constructor Test");

    BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE(list.Size() == 0, "Constructor Test, Size not 0");

    Footer ("Constructor Test");
}

void Compare(DListT list, vector<string> check) {
    size_t i;

    cout << "in compare" << endl;
    if (list.Size() != check.size()) {
        BOOST_FAIL("Sizes not the same in Compare");
    } else {
        for(i = 0; i < check.size(); i++) {
             BOOST_CHECK(list.Data() == check[i]);
             list.Right();
        }
    }

    cout << "exiting compare" << endl;
    return;
    
}

void CompareHome(DListT list, vector<string> check) {
    // we don't know that current is pointing to the right thing.
    list.Home();
    cout << "entering comparehome" << endl;
    Compare(list, check);
    cout << "exiting comparehome" << endl;
}

// not really checking current directly.
// since both are at the "same" value of current, they should be the same.
// this will not work if the pattern repeats and the current pointer is at
// a offset
//

void CompareLists(DListT & a, DListT & b) {
    size_t i;

    if (a.Size() != b.Size()) {
        BOOST_FAIL("Sizes not the same in CompareLists");
    } else { 
        for(i = 0; i < a.Size(); i++) {
             BOOST_CHECK(a.Data() == b.Data());
             a.Right();
             b.Right();
        }
        BOOST_CHECK(a.Data() == b.Data());
    }
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(insert_test) {
    DListT list;
    vector<string> check;

    Header("Insert Test");

    CompareHome(list, check);

    //   head->A
    list.Insert("A");
    cout << "inserting a" << endl;
    check = {"A"};
    CompareHome(list, check);

    // head->B<->A
    list.Insert("B");
    cout << "inserting b" << endl;
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= list.Size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "list has: " << list.Data() << endl;
        cout << "i is: " << i << endl;
        list.Right();
        
    }
    
    list.Home();
    check = {"B","A"};
    CompareHome(list, check);

    // head->B<->C<->A
    list.Home();
    list.Right();
    list.Insert("C");
    check = {"B","C","A"};
    CompareHome(list, check);

    // head->D<->B<->C<->A
    list.Home();
    list.Insert("D");
    check = {"D","B","C","A"};
    CompareHome(list, check);

    // head->D<->B<->C<->E<->A
    list.Home();
    list.Left();
    list.Insert("E");
    check = {"D","B","C","E","A"};
    CompareHome(list, check);

    // head->D<->B<->C<->E<->A
    list.Home();
    list.Left();
    list.Left();
    list.Left();
    list.Insert("F");
    check = {"D","B","F","C","E","A"};
    CompareHome(list, check);

    Footer("Insert Test");
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(copy_test) {
    DListT list1, list2;

    Header("Copy-Copy Constructor Test");

    // check empty lists
    // the first case should have an output error for now.  Just supress it 
    output_test_stream output; 
    streambuf * old = cout.rdbuf(output.rdbuf());
    CompareLists(list1, list2);
    cout.rdbuf(old);  

    // check list with single element
    list1.Insert("A");
    list2 = list1;
    CompareLists(list1, list2);

    DListT list3(list1);
    CompareLists(list1, list3);


    // check lists with two elements
    list1.Insert("B");
    list2 = list1;
    CompareLists(list1, list2);

    DListT list4(list1);
    CompareLists(list1, list4);

    // let's try a handful of elements.
    list1.Insert("C");
    list1.Insert("D");
    list1.Insert("E");
    list2 = list1;
    CompareLists(list1, list2);

    DListT list5(list1);
    CompareLists(list1, list5);

    // did we get the current pointer right?
    list1.Right();
    list1.Right();
    list1.Right();
    list2 = list1;
    CompareLists(list1, list2);

    DListT list6(list1);
    CompareLists(list1, list6);

    Footer("Copy-Copy Constructor Test");
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(empty_data_access_test) {
    DListT list;

    Header("Empty Data Access Test");

    // set up a stream buffer to capture the output
    output_test_stream output; 

    // cause output to occur.
    streambuf * old = cout.rdbuf(output.rdbuf());

    string x = list.Data();

    // restore the stdout buffer
    cout.rdbuf(old);  

    BOOST_CHECK( !output.is_empty( false ) );
    BOOST_CHECK( output.is_equal( "Error: Attempt to access Empty List.\n" ) );
    BOOST_CHECK( x == "NO DATA");

    Footer("Empty Data Access Test");
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(left_right_home_test) {
    Header("Movement Test");

    DListT list, listCopy;

    vector<string> check;

    list.Insert("D");
    list.Insert("C");
    list.Insert("B");
    list.Insert("A");

    list.Home();
    check = {"A","B","C","D"};
    listCopy = list;
    Compare(listCopy,check);

    list.Right();
    check = {"B","C","D","A"};
    listCopy = list;
    Compare(listCopy,check);

    list.Right();
    check = {"C","D","A","B"};
    listCopy = list;
    Compare(listCopy,check);

    list.Right();
    check = {"D","A","B","C"};
    listCopy = list;
    Compare(listCopy,check);

    list.Right();
    check = {"A","B","C","D"};
    listCopy = list;
    Compare(listCopy,check);

    list.Home();
    list.Left();
    check = {"D", "A","B","C"};
    Compare(list,check);

    list.Left();
    check = {"C", "D", "A","B"};
    Compare(list,check);

    list.Left();
    check = {"B", "C", "D", "A"};
    Compare(list,check);

    list.Left();
    check = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
    Compare(list,check);

    Footer("Movement Test");
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(delete_test) {
    Header("Delete Test");

    DListT list;
    vector<string> check;

    list.Insert("G");
    list.Insert("F");
    list.Insert("E");
    list.Insert("D");
    list.Insert("C");
    list.Insert("B");
    list.Insert("A");

    check = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G"};

    CompareHome(list,check);

    // delete the head of the list
    list.Home();
    list.Delete();

    // delete the last item in the list;
    list.Home();
    list.Left();
    list.Delete();
    check = {"B","C","D","E","F"};
    CompareHome(list,check);

    // delete the second to last item
    list.Home();
    list.Left();
    list.Left();
    list.Delete();
    check = {"B","C","D","F"};
    CompareHome(list,check);

    // delete the second item
    list.Home();
    list.Right();
    list.Delete();
    check = {"B","D","F"};
    CompareHome(list,check);

    list.Home();
    list.Delete();
    check = {"D","F"};
    CompareHome(list,check);

    list.Home();
    list.Delete();
    check = {"F"};
    CompareHome(list,check);

    list.Delete();
    check = {};
    CompareHome(list,check);

    Footer("Delete Test");
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

here is my makefile

```
CXXFLAGS =  -g -O3 -Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wmisleading-indentation -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wshadow -Wconversion -Werror -std=c++17

OBJS = DListTTest 

all: ${OBJS}

test: DListTTest
    ./DListTTest

memcheck: DListTTest
    valgrind --leak-check=summary ./DListTTest
        
DListTTest: DListT.o

clean:
    rm -f ${OBJS} *.o
```

Comment: This is pretty far from a [**minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You posted a lot of code. Is this all necessary to demonstrate the problem? Remember the main purpose of your question is to help future readers. I think with this much code they will pass and move on to a different example to help solve their problem.

Comment: *but when it reaches "b" and tries to call the copy constructor again* -- `list2 = list1;` -- That uses the assignment operator, not the copy constructor.

Comment: i think so, i just wanted to make sure it has everything needed to run

Comment: *"here is my professor's test code"* -- this should not be part of the question. Mercilessly hack this down to the bare minimum needed to reproduce your problem. Wanting to make sure it has everything needed to run is good, but you need to use more finesse. Don't just dump all of your code. Take some time to experiment. Remove various pieces until removing anything else will either cause the code to fail to compile or to run without the infinite loop.

Comment: It looks like you've added lots of diagnostic messages to help you track down the problem. This is good, but don't keep it to yourself. After you've simplified your code to a [mre] with diagnostics, add the output to your question so we can see where the infinite loop occurs. (Still, I would simplify these diagnostics a bit. You don't need two diagnostic messages between each line of code; one is sufficient. Up to you which you want to keep.)